# Need to include HTML code into the JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to call a HTML tag from the jQuery file. I tried lots of times and a lot of methods. Can anyone suggest me how I can implement this HTML tag in JS code?

If I click the button it needs to check the `if` condition. If it enters the `else`, I need to popup the small dialog box.

```js
$("#validate").on('click', function() {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  var emailID = $('#email').val();
  var bool = emailReg.test(emailID);
  console.log("the bool is", bool)
  if (bool == false || emailID == null || emailID == "") {
    alert("invalid email")
  } else {
    window.location.href = '"#small-dialog';
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="small-dialog" class="dialog dialog-sm zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
  <h1>Confirm Again</h1>
  <p>Still you need to unSubscribe your email from enlisted list. Please click "Yes" below or if you don't want to unSubscribe , then please click "No" </p>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <input type="button" class="btn" id="submit" style="background-color: darkred; color: white" value="Yes">
      <button onClick="parent.location='Confirm_Unsubscribe.html'" class="btn  " style="background-color: darkred; color: white">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for a "hash-url" just use `window.location.hash` rather than `window.location.href`. But this will only scroll to where `#small-dialog` is on the page - and if it's currently hidden then it won't magically make it appear. Can you not just write a simple JS function to make the element display?